# Three.js render performance with and without multiple materials (both with textures)

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to figure out if the significant performance hit I'm seeing is something that can be optimized away or is this the state of things:

I have a geometry that looks like Obama, it's about 11K triangles, 5600 or so faces (both quads and triangles). It was modeled in Maya, and is exported as OBJ in one of two methods depending upon the render method being used.

In one export method, we do not export the materials file from Maya. We take the 5 different texture maps used by the model, stitch them into a single texture and re-write the UVs in the model to reference the new texture locations in the unified texture. The final unified texture is 1024x512.

The 2nd export method does use the exported materials file from Maya, and we reduce the 5 different textures to be smaller in all cases than their counterpart in the unified texture used by the other method. If the 5 different textures were tiled, you'd get something about 768x512.

The only other difference between the two methods of rendering the same geometry is the second method has 1 semi-transparent material: the cornea (the clear layer) over the eyes is set to 0.1 (barely visible) transparency and a slightly blue/gray tint.

In place of the semi-transparent cornea in the first rendering method, we simply have the image of the eyeball on the cornea, and the inner eye (iris and pupil) are never seen by this method. They are there, just discarded by rendering because they are behind the opaque cornea.

Now here's the big puzzle: render method 1 easily hits 60 fps and stays there with two such geometries. Render method 2 is rendering between 20 and 25 frames per second. I've not tried rendering with a second geometry yet. I'm somewhat surprised at this significant reduction in my frame rate. If I change the semi-transparent cornea to be opaque, the frame rate is still poor (same rate).

Both methods use the THREE.JSONLoader. Render method 1 uses a single MeshLambertMaterial, and render method 2 uses meshFaceMaterial and the array of 6 materials.

Is there that much of a hit from using multiple materials and multiple textures? What are people doing with more complex environments requiring exponentially more materials than my paltry 6?

Comment: What version of three.js are you using? r.60 does not support quads. Make sure all your textures are power-of-two (POT), e.g., 1024 x 512, and try again.

Comment: I'm on R59 - not moving to R60 until we rework our pipeline because of the loss of quads. Also, just tried on the latest Chrome and I'm seeing better performance, but irregular. Same frame, nothing moving or changing, and the Chrome fps is jumping from lo-40 to 60 up and down. temp link that will not be up forever of the 2nd render method: https://dev.3d-avatar-store.com/a3da-multiMatTest/2033

Comment: Why would textures make a difference if they're so small? Texture atlases are usually even bigger. Something about multiple materials seems wrong, like something is being recalculated multiple times and discarded. Do you have some flickering on screen?

Comment: I'm starting to think this is an issue under OSX and primarily Firefox. Same OSX 8-core 2.3 Ghz i7 MBP, fresh reboot, Chrome 29.0.1547.57 is 47-60 fps, Firefox 23.0.1 is 22-30 fps, Safari 6.0.5 is a solid 60 fps, and on a separate 8-core 3.4 Ghz i7 Win8.1 desktop we're seeing a solid 60 fps on Firefox, Chrome & IE, all latest versions on the Windows browsers.

Comment: Generically, you are substituting multiple draw calls for a single one in the second method. That is likely to slow things down, although this seems like a bit hit.